# Entity Framework. Check pending request before execute procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in my ASP.MVC project that just get data from a database. I've mapped it in Entity Framework. The data in a database changes very quickly, so from time to time execution of my stored procedure is failed with an error:

```
"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction"
```

Can I check if any pending requests are running before execute my procedure in EF?

Or maybe someone can advise me some other solution for this problem?

Comment: This may be related to the way you are instantiating and using your Entity Framework Dbcontext / ObjectContext.  Can you tell us what type of app environment you have?  (i.e ASP.NET, WinForms, Console app)

Comment: See the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26235105/4275342). I hope this helps